# Extracting text in R

Tags: regex, r, text, extract, substr

I am trying to extract a variable-length substring of text using R. I have several characters such as the following:

```
"\"/Users/Nel/Documents/Project/Data/dataset.csv\""
```

I need to extract the file path from each such character. In this case what I am trying to get is:

```
path1 <- "/Users/Nel/Documents/Project/Data/dataset.csv"
```

I am able to use the substring function:

```
path1 <- substr("\"/Users/Nel/Documents/Project/Data/dataset.csv\"", 3, 46)
```

with the indices hard-coded to get what I want in this particular instance. However, this particular path is one of many, and I need to be able to find these indices on the fly. I believe the

```
grep()
```

function could work but I can't figure out the relevant regular expressions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are just trying to remove some hard-coded quotation marks.

Try `gsub`:

```
x
# [1] "\"/Users/Nel/Documents/Project/Data/dataset.csv\""
gsub('\"',"",x)
# [1] "/Users/Nel/Documents/Project/Data/dataset.csv"
## or 
# gsub('["]', "", x)
```